# Remap Command Key When Using Remote X11 Application On Mac

Tags: macos, xorg, remapping

I have a Redhat application that I run on my OSX desktop via a remote X11 session.  Everything works fine except keyboard shortcuts.  I can copy with Command C but I have to use Control P rather than Command P to paste.  Also I can't save with Command S.

I would like to remap left command to control for all X11 sessions.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[KeyRemap4MacBook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/index.html) lets you do this.

- Install KeyRemap4MacBook
- Restart your Mac
- Open KeyRemap4MacBook Preferences
- Expand "Change Command_L Key"
- Check Command_L to Control_L (only in X11)